# Saving an input field in different languages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-i18n

**Context** 
In my bike reservation app, `bike_owners` can add a description in my app about the `bike` they are renting out.

As `website visitors` (customers) have the option to select a language (say English, French and German), I would like to give `bike_owners` the opportunity to create a separate description for every language.

As this is about users creating a descriptions for several languages, instead of my app being available in several languages I cannot seem to use the i18n classic approach.

**Question**
How to deal with users providing input for a database table_column in multiple languages?

**Potential approach**
There must be a smarter way to go about this, but the only solution I found/came up with to actually deal with inputs for multiple languages, is to actually create multiple columns in my database bike_table, each representing a description in an individual language (`description_en`, `description_fr`, `description_de` etc.).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) or [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @max thanks! These are indeed the type of solutions I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Max suggestion, I used the Globalize gem. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you may split these in a new text table with these attributes: id, language_id, used_for, text_body

by this solution, you will add in rows not columns
this is an example for a row

```
113, 2, description, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```